# Detect Google Chrome in Kiosk Mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, kiosk-mode

how to detect if the user using Google Chrome in kiosk mode?

I want to know if the user is using chrome in kiosk mode if it is not for me to display a message to put teaching so she can use the resources that only the kiosk mode can provide

Answer (score 10):

You can check the `isKioskSession` property on the `launchData` object you get from the [chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime#event-onLaunched) event.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  if (launchData.isKioskSession) {
      // yes, we are in kiosk mode
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

The above answer assumes that you are in a [Chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps). If you are trying to detect whether a page is in a Chrome browser launched with the --kiosk option, I don't know of a way to detect that. However, this is functionally equivalent to running in fullscreen mode, which you can detect with the [Fullscreen API](http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen).

```
var fullscreenEnabled = document.fullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullScreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled;
```

Comment: I think he was talking about normal Chrome running in Kiosk mode, not a Chrome app. The detect fullscreen code you mentioned is just for checking if the browser **supports** fullscreen, not if it's currently in fullscreen. Any other solutions? I have the same problem and detecting based on `screen.availHeight` and `window.innerHeight` doesn't work if the user zooms in, making it break.

Comment: mmm but if i want url bar to be visible i want to use --kiosk so no full screen, your solution may work with --kiosk-printing