# Detect Chrome kiosk mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, kiosk-mode

I've seen other questions asking the same thing, with answers that were accepted. However, those answers don't always work.

This was the accepted answer:

```
if (screen.availHeight || screen.height-30) <= window.innerHeight) {
    // code
}
```

And yes, that works, but not if the users zooms in on the page. I run a website in kiosk mode (**not a Chrome app**) on 2 public PCs in an apartment complex for elderly people.

I need to detect users coming from those two PCs to add some extra code seeing as everything would mess up if they click a link going to a different website or click a link to a PDF file. There's no tabs so there would be no way to get back to the original website so I inject code to open external links in an iframe.

How can I detect users coming from those PCs with just a normal Chrome installation? An extension that could do the trick would also be welcome.

Comment: If an answer does not work and you have the same question, post a comment explaining why it does not work, and downvote it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Google Chome in Kiosk Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666522/detect-google-chome-in-kiosk-mode)

Comment: The question you linked is regarding a Chrome app, I mentioned I'm not in a Chrome app.

Comment: Why do you think that [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666522/detect-google-chome-in-kiosk-mode) is regarding a Chrome app? It's not even tagged [google-chrome-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-app)!

Comment: Did you even read the answer of the question you linked? It says: "The above answer assumes that you are in a Chrome app." I am not in a Chrome app, I'm just in the Chrome browser with --kiosk added to the startup parameters. Those are two very different things.

Comment: That is the *answer*, not the *question*. Also note the current answer there goes on to describe one option to `detect whether a page is in a Chrome browser launched with the --kiosk option`.